# How to check if the currently viewed page is an endpoint in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress, url-rewriting, endpoints

I have added an endpoint to author links using `add_rewrite_endpoint()`

I can now have links such as: `example.com/author/username/articles`

To check when the currently viewed page is the author page (`example.com/author/username`) I can do this:

```
if ( is_author() )
```

But how can I check if the currently viewed page is my new endpoint? i.e: `example.com/author/username/articles`

Ref:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_endpoint
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_author

Answer (score 8):

I found the answer:

```
global $wp_query;
isset( $wp_query->query_vars['articles'] )
```

Comment: At some moment you gotta write a blog post: `Mastering endpoints, by henry wright` ;)

Comment: @brasofilo someone beat me to it :) - Take a look at this post, it explains everything: https://make.wordpress.org/plugins/2012/06/07/rewrite-endpoints-api/

Comment: Or use ```get_query_var( 'articles', false ) !== false```

Comment: This is not working if some passing `set_query_var('articles', $articles)` into the template scope.